# Find and replace the nth element in a delimited data file using notepad++ regex

Tags: regex, replace, find, notepad++

Given a delimited text file like below(separated by |), I need to find the nth element and replace it with new value.

```
1|ppp|168|.20||3|00100|RNRBT5|VS08|RCK|150W|TE21|TE21|||||||RA|CXXXXXX|29|30|290|300|1|X|Q8|.2002||00003|00100|RN|VS|RCKR|150W|TE21|TE21|||||||RM|CXXXXXX|29|30|90|300
1|ppp|168|.20||3|00100|RNRBT5|VS08|RCK|150W|TE21|TE21|||||||RA|CXXXXXX|29|30|290|300|1|X|Q8|.2002||00003|00100|RN|VS|RCKR|150W|TE21|TE21|||||||RM|CXXXXXX|29|30|90|300
1|ppp|168|.20||3|00100|RNRBT5|VS08|RCK|150W|TE21|TE21|||||||RA|CXXXXXX|29|30|290|300|1|X|Q8|.2002||00003|00100|RN|VS|RCKR|150W|TE21|TE21|||||||RM|CXXXXXX|29|30|90|300
1|ppp|168|.20||3|00100|RNRBT5|VS08|RCK|150W|TE21|TE21|||||||RA|CXXXXXX|29|30|290|300|1|X|Q8|.2002||00003|00100|RN|VS|RCKR|150W|TE21|TE21|||||||RM|CXXXXXX|29|30|90|300
```

example replacement requirement are like below:

```
find the 4th element ".20" at 1st line and replace it with a velue like "jko"
find the 6th element "3" at 1st line and replace it with a velue like "uo"
find the 10th element "RCK" at 2nd line and replace it with a velue like "ko"
```

**Solution I have tried**

find with Regex(try to find and replace the 4th element)
`^(?:[^\|]*\|){3}([^\|]*)`
with this match result is

```
1|ppp|168|.20
```

and the group 1 result is `.20`

I stuck here because I can't find a way to replace only the group 1 result

Comment: That is because you wrapped the wrong part, `^((?:[^\|]*\|){3})[^\|]*` -> `${1}jko`. Or, `^(?:[^\|]*\|){3}\K[^\|]*` => `jko`

Comment: ^(?:[^\|]*\|){3}\K[^\|]*, this works, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope you meant this .
Find what: `(^.*?\.)20(\|\|)3(.*?)rck`
Replace with: `$1jko$2uo$3ko`